# MC Access: Create Select query that always returns value

Tags: sql, ms-access, if-statement, select

Good day! I hope someone can help me. Below I wrote down my structure and question.
I have this invoice details table:
**Invoice Details Table**

```
 Invoice | Detail | Product | Price | VAT % | VAT € | TOTAL |
 ------- | -------|---------|-------|-------|-------|-------|
 0001    |   1    |     X   | € 100 |  21   | € 21  | € 121 |
 0001    |   2    |     X   | € 200 |  21   | € 42  | € 242 |
 0001    |   3    |     X   | € 100 |   6   | €  6  | € 106 |
```

Now I want to make a select query to get the following values:

**Desired query result:**

```
 Invoice | SumofVAT 6% | SumofVAT 21% | 
 ------- | ------------|--------------|
 0001    |   €6        |     € 63     |
```

After this query I can use an update query to write this Data to my invoice table:

```
 Invoice | Client | Date    | Price | VAT 6% | VAT 21% |
 ------- | -------|---------|-------|--------|---------|
 0001    |   B10  |01-01-01 | € 469 |  € 6   | € 63    |
```

I have tried many things. The problem I run into is that when a particular only has one or more products with 1 type of VAT in %. Then the query returns Null.

I think I should have:

1) a query to calculate total VAT 6% in € for invoice xxxx ( return invoice number and total vat of 6%)

2) a query to calculate total VAT 21% in € for invoice xxxx  ( return invoice number and total vat of 21%)

**3) If one of these queries returns Null it should return invoice number and total number of VAT € 0,00**

Hope someone can help me with this.

Image of the 6% QUERY: (21% is equal but criteria is '21')

[image: query of 6%]

**SQL VERSION:**

```
 SELECT FactuurDetails.Factuurnummer, FactuurDetails.[BTW in %],Sum(FactuurDetails.[BTW in EURO]) AS [SumOfBTW in EURO]
 FROM FactuurDetails
 GROUP BY FactuurDetails.Factuurnummer, FactuurDetails.[BTW in %]
 HAVING (((FactuurDetails.Factuurnummer)=[Forms]![Facturen]!
```

Here you see if a invoice only has products with 21% ( or the other way around ) the query result will be empty.

Comment: Share your query that you have tried to get the above result.

Comment: share ur query as text code plz

Comment: We need the SQL version of your query to be able to help you

Comment: Writing these things into your Invoices table is wrong. It violates relational design principles of normalization, and introduces a transitive depency. Unless you have objective reasons to denormalize, don't do that.

Answer (score 2):

Surely not the answer you expect, and I will receive a few negative vote, but let's go:
**Writing these things into your Invoices table is wrong**: it violates relational design principles of normalization, and introduces a transitive depency.

Unless you have objective reasons to denormalize, don't do that.

Additionally, with a correct design, your *Invoice* records will have to be created BEFORE the *InvoiceDetails*, otherwise you can't implement Referential Integrity.

I strongly suggest that your read a bit mmore about [relational database design and normalization](http://r937.com/relational.html).

As a very simplified rule: don't store what can be recalculated, unless you need it for historical reason (but here you keep the Tax history in the Details)

---

To calculate your VAT totals, you can do it like this:

```
SELECT Invoices.Id, Details.VatRate, Sum([Quant]*[unitprice]*[VatRate]) AS VatAmount
FROM Invoices LEFT JOIN Details ON Invoices.Id = Details.InvId
GROUP BY Invoices.Id, Details.VatRate;
```

or with a crosstab query:

```
TRANSFORM Sum([Quant]*[unitprice]*[VatRate]) AS VatAmount
SELECT Invoices.Id
FROM Invoices LEFT JOIN Details ON Invoices.Id = Details.InvId
GROUP BY Invoices.Id
PIVOT Details.VatRate;
```

Comment: I understand, but my invoice records ARE created before the invoicedetails. Only the VAT needs to be updated because my invoice detail records create these when someone changes the product amount in the invoice for some reason. So the only data that is added to the invoice records is the amount of VAT in EURO. The rest is already there.

Comment: That's fine. But if your VAT total are not *stored* on the Order, but rather calculated, they will not need to be *updated*.

Comment: They are stored. But as a total amount and not seperated by 6% and 21 %. And to make an-easy-to-read table for our finance ladies i want this to be separeted.

Comment: For the finance ladies, you create a QUERY, or an Excel sheet that pulls the data from Access db. Final layout (nearly) NEVER dictates the structure of the db !!!

Comment: I understand this, you are right. But I hope you can than help me how to create this query of separate BTW sums as described above. Never mind the update statement i mentioned. If I can have a query that shows the sums of 6% and 21 % of a certain invoice I would be very happy.

Comment: @BasSchreuder I have worked on this kind of thing for a number of years and would remind you that VAT rates change, so 21% may become 15% or 22%. Use a cross tab, as suggested by iDevlop with VAT rate as a column header. The query wizard will guide you.

Comment: @Fionnuala thanks. Your crosstab suggestion..could you explain me how this would create sums of VAT totals per vat % and invoice like in my main question ? I have just tried a view times, but crosstabs are new for me.

Comment: TRANSFORM Sum(InvoiceDetail.[VAT]) AS SumOfVAT
SELECT InvoiceDetail.[Invoice], Sum(InvoiceDetail.[VAT]) AS [Total Of VAT]
FROM InvoiceDetail
GROUP BY InvoiceDetail.[Invoice]
PIVOT InvoiceDetail.[VAT%];

Comment: @Fionnuala: You are close with the above. You need something for his 3rd constraint: "3) If one of these queries returns Null it should return invoice number and total number of VAT € 0,00"

Answer (score 0):

You could try this. I have tested it myself and I think it gets you the expected result.

```
SELECT I1 AS Invoice, six.t AS VAT_6, twentyone.t AS VAT_21
FROM 
    (SELECT Invoice AS I1, IIF(ISNULL(sum(VAT)),0,sum(VAT)) AS t 
    FROM Table1 WHERE [vat%] = 6 GROUP BY Invoice) AS six 
        RIGHT JOIN 
    (SELECT Invoice AS I2, IIF(ISNULL(sum(VAT)),0,sum(VAT)) AS t 
    FROM Table1 WHERE [vat%] = 21 GROUP BY Invoice) AS twentyone ON six.I1 = twentyone.I2
UNION
SELECT I1 AS Invoice, six.t AS VAT_6, twentyone.t AS VAT_21
FROM 
    (SELECT Invoice AS I1, IIF(ISNULL(sum(VAT)),0,sum(VAT)) AS t 
    FROM Table1 WHERE [vat%] = 6 GROUP BY Invoice) AS six 
        LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT Invoice AS I2, IIF(ISNULL(sum(VAT)),0,sum(VAT)) AS t 
    FROM Table1 WHERE [vat%] = 21 GROUP BY Invoice) AS twentyone ON six.I1 = twentyone.I2
```

I don't know if it is the right practise to do it liek that but as far as I am concerned it does what is supposed to do and described above.

**EDIT:** Here is the data table I have created from your example
and the result as screenshots

**Table**
[image]

**Result**

[image]

Comment: Why not crosstab? This is potentially very slow indeed.

Comment: Yes it could be slow if you have a really large db (I doubt this is the case - you don't use MS Access if you have large/complicated DBs). But the query itself is as simple as it can get. Without using anything "special" it does what is expected to do. It is not beautiful or elegant but it works.

Comment: Access is a RAD tool, the database could be anything.

Comment: I will give you that, the database could be anything (Though I still don't think that he is going to have perfomance issues). The fact remains that this is the simplest query you can get to do the work correctly.
EDIT: And by simplest I mean not using cross tab and pivot

Answer (score 0):

To get a Sum on values that may include Null , all you need is to replace:

`[Value_that_may_be_Null]` with `Nz([Value_that_may_be_Null],0)` in your query (work both in the graphical query designer and Access SQL)